# How to add images to UIPageViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` with 5 screens. Please see the below image

[image]

I need to add some images instead of the label **Screen #1**, **Screen #2**, etc.

[Here is my code](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B09k-AL37qBwazNZa3dQNEtTWWM/edit?usp=sharing)

Can anyone please tell me the solution?

Comment: So add `UIImageView`'s instead of `UILabel` (programmatically or through XIB, which ever way you are following)

Comment: @Amar: I know the design point of view. How to add image programatically inside UIImageView ?

Comment: @user1745838 follow my code.

Comment: Every `UIImageView` has an `image` property which accepts `UIImage` instance. Get your image as `UIImage` (can be static image or downloaded from URL), then assign it to the image view property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

Add whatever yor images in your imageArray  array;

```
NSArray *imageArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"SpaceTheme.png",@"BeachTheme.png",@"vintage.png", nil];

ScrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,480)];
[Scroll setPagingEnabled:YES];
[Scroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

for(n=0; n< [imageArray count];n++)
   {

    NSString *imageName=[imageArray objectAtIndex:n];

        NSString *fullImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName];
        CGRect imageViewFrame;



            int padding=20;
            imageViewFrame=CGRectMake(Scroll.frame.size.width*n+padding-10,Scroll.frame.origin.y-130,Scroll.frame.size.width-1*padding, Scroll.frame.size.height);


        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];

        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fullImageName]];

        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

        [Scroll addSubview:imageView];

        pagecontrol.numberOfPages = 3;   // Give numbre of pages here 
        pagecontrol.currentPage = 0;

        [self.view addSubview:pagecontrol]; 
    }
    Scroll.delegate=(id)self;
    CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(Scroll.frame.size.width*[imageArray count], Scroll.frame.size.height);
    [Scroll setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
    [self.view addSubview:Scroll];
```